# PHP Contact Form to Mail not working

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

Good day everyone, this is my first time to post here so pls bear with me. I need your help guys, I'm an artist that knows basic html5/css that's why i'm really not good in php.

Anyway I have a project that has a contact form, I just realized that yahoo mail is not working when I fill up the form online, but gmail's are good. Below is my php code. I've been following this [PHP Mail() Contact-us form works fine if entering a Gmail sending address, but not with Yahoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133442/php-mail-contact-us-form-works-fine-if-entering-a-gmail-sending-address-but-n) but I really can't do it on my own! A brother needs your help. Thank you.

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_brand = $_POST['cf_brand'];
$field_category = $_POST['cf_category'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_facebook = $_POST['cf_facebook'];
$field_instagram = $_POST['cf_instagram'];
$field_number = $_POST['cf_number'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com';
$subject = 'DULCET LIFESTYLE - BECOME FAMILY: '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From Owner: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Brand Name: '.$field_brand."\n";
$body_message .= 'Brand Category: '.$field_category."\n";
$body_message .= 'Email: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Facebook: '.$field_facebook."\n";
$body_message .= 'Instagram: '.$field_instagram."\n";
$body_message .= 'Number: '.$field_number."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'becomefamily.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'becomefamily.htm';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Replace you gmail id to yahoo email id in `$mail_to = 'dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com';
`

Comment: @RohanKumar but 'dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com' is the one that should receive the data from the contact form. :( :(

Comment: I'm confused. If you are wanting to send an email to a gmail address and it is working what is the problem?

Comment: @JeremyFabia are you talking about yahoo email id from `$_POST['cf_email']` field or you want to receive email on your yahoo email id?

Comment: @RamRaider I'm sorry for the confusion. Yes, I would like to send an email to a gmail by any mail used whether gmail or yahoomail. But only gmail works, and yahoomail doesn't. :(

Comment: @RohanKumar yes i'm talking about that one $_POST['cf_emai'] because when yahoomail is used for the data, 'dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com' doesn't receive it.

Comment: Why would you want to forge the FROM field?  Leave the FROM as default.   And try their email address as the REPLY TO as you have done.

Comment: Check your Junk/Spam folder too, may be mails resides in it.

Comment: @Progrock sorry not familiar with php :( what do you mean leave the From as default, and use the email 'dulcetlifestylehub@gmail.com' in $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n"; is that it? :(

Comment: At a minimum you can use Php's mail function with its first three arguments:  To, Subject and Message.  Mail sent this way will most likely originate from your web server.  Try it.  For you the important part is to collect the user info, and embed that into a message.  By changing the From address in your mail (by adding a header), some mail providers may identify the mail as spam.  The Reply-To header is a convenience.  On receipt of the mail, your email client may use that address for the To field in your reply.  Start by testing a few basic messages to either your Gmail or Yahoo accounts.